Sampling nonhomogeneous inter-arrival times of a Poisson process
In the book Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation, it is the described how we sample the inter-arrival times of a nonhomogeneous Poisson process on p. 251:

The theory is clear to me and I can formally verify that $T_{n+1}$ is conditionally distributed as $$T_n+F_{\tau_n}^{-1}(1-e^{-E})=\Lambda^{-1}(E+\Lambda(T_n))$$ given $T_n$, where I denoted $F$ by $F_t$ for better clarity.
However, in light of this, I don't understand why they update $T$ as $\color{red}{T+}\Lambda^{-1}(E+\Lambda(T))$ in the algorithm. Shouldn't it be $T\leftarrow\Lambda^{-1}(E+\Lambda(T))$ instead?
